# What is the maximum number of Sql Elastic Pool you can have in Gen 5?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server, azure-elasticpool

I am trying to figure some things in azure sql but I couldn't find any helpful documentations? I know the maximum number of database in Gen5 tier per server instance is 5000. I also know the sql elastic pool max data storage size is 5TB. Based on this I have the following questions

1. Worst case scenario, one pool for one database, does that mean the max number of elastic pool in sql server instance is 5000, with each max db storage size of 4TB
2. If I have standalone database (without elastic pool), what is the max db storage a database can have per sql instance?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your questions:

1. Maximum number of elastic pools per logical server. That is limited by number of DTUs or vCores. For example, if each pool is 1000 DTUs, then a server can support 54 pools. You can find more information **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-logical-server#logical-server-limits)**. The maximum size of a database assigned to a pool depends on the model (**[DTU-model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-elastic-pools)**, **[vCore-model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases)**)
2. Por standalone databases the size limit (max data size) depends on the tier and the model (**[DTU-model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-dtu-single-databases)**, **[vCore-Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-vcore-single-databases)**)